# CollapsingToolbar doesnt work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a main activity ​​with a hiding toolbar, and a tabLayout. In the tabs - fragments. In one of the fragments, there is also a hiding toolbar, and a recyclerView. How to make, that at a scroll at first the toolbar in a activity collapses, then
in the fragment? 
Now, if I scrolling, collapsingToolbar in fragment works correctly, but main activity toolbar doesnt work.
As example - application "Lamoda", second tab - categories

main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="araikovichinc.lamodabyaraikovich.Activities.HomeActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home_appbar">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_tool_bar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Девушкам"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/select_sex_title_home"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="90"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/home_linerlayout">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/woman_image_home"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:src="@drawable/woman"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/man_image_home"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/man"/>
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/child_image_home"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/kids"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/Black">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sex_image_category"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/woman"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/category_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```